# C# program hangs on Socket.Accept()

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I created a server "middleman" application that uses sockets and multi-threading techniques (ServerListener is run in a new thread). I found early on that when I would use the Socket.Accept() method, the program would hang indefinitely, waiting for that connection to happen.  The problem is, as far as I can tell there is no reason for it not to.

I spent a good portion of the day trying lots of different things to make it work, and somewhere something changed because it suddenly started working for a while.  However, as soon as I accidentally chose a different data source than "localhost" for the client application, the problem popped back up again.  I have tried running the program without the firewall OR antivirus running, but no luck.  The client program IS set to connect on port 10000.  Here is my code:

```
    public void ServerListener() {
        UpdateStatus("Establishing link to server");
        server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, defaultPort));
        server.Listen(queue);
        UpdateStatus("Accepting Connections");
        while (true) {
            Socket client = default(Socket);
            try {
                client = server.Accept();
                if (client != null) {
                    ++count;
                    UpdateCount(count.ToString());
                    new Thread(
                    () => {
                        Client myclient = new Client(client, defaultPort, this);
                    }
                    ).Start();
                }
            }
            catch( Exception ex ){
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

It will run just fine right up until server.Accept(), then hangs.  As stated, it did work for a while earlier, but is now hanging again.  I've tried to see if any other programs are using port 10000, and they aren't.  I went over and over this with a friend, and we couldn't find the problem.  Please help!

*EDIT* To be clear, I do know that Accept is a blocking call.  The client program makes the connection on port 10000, but this program keeps on waiting on the Accept as if nothing happened.  It did work for a time, so I know the connection is working like it is supposed to from the client program's end.  However, I can't fathom why this program is now acting like that connection never happens, and continues to wait on the Accept.

Comment: But that is how it is suppose to work. `Accept` is blocking call.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear.  Accept is blocking, but once it makes the connection it should move on, right?  The connection comes in from the client program, but accept keeps waiting as if nothing happened

Comment: Yes, until the next call to `Accept` in your loop. Sounds like you have trouble debugging the multithreaded code.

Comment: It seems that you want to accept a single connection. If that's the case, why loop at all?

Comment: There may be multiple client connections at once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Accept` blocks on purpose. If you want to do other things while waiting for another client to connect you can:

1. Run the `ServerListener` in another Thread or better - a long running task:

   ```
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   ...
   Task.Factory.StartNew(ServerListener, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
   ```
2. Use the [`AcceptAsync` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.acceptasync.aspx) which uses the [`SocketAsyncEventArgs` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx). For that to work, you create a new `SocketAsyncEventArgs` instance, set its values and pass it to `socket.AcceptAsync`.

Comment: Why is a long running task better?

Comment: It's a higher level of abstraction, abstraction is particularly useful when someone's having trouble understanding a concept.

Comment: ServerListener is being run in another thread.  Trying to use the AcceptAsync method, but having a hard time seeing how to apply it to this situation; what kind of values would my SocketAsyncEventArgs have?

Comment: Got it figured out, AcceptAsync did end up being helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Gusdor `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` signals to the TaskFactory that this thread you will be giving me will unlikely be returned any time soon. The implication being that instead of the task factory taking a thread from the threadpool, a new thread is created.